# Reboot Linux laptop from the command line gracefully

Tags: linux, command-line, xorg, kde

In a script, I want to reboot my Linux  laptop like the reboot button in the KDE GUI.

In KDE, if there is a program open with unsaved files, those programs show a message, "Do you want to save your files?".

I have tried `reboot` and even:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Reboot" boolean:true
```

But these commands just reboot after killing all programs without confirmation.

Is there a CLI command that will trigger a graceful shutdown of applications running under KDE?

Comment: Your title does not match your question. Please [edit] and clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send a reboot request to the KDE session manager instead. For example:

```
# New interface:
dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest="org.kde.Shutdown" \
    /Shutdown org.kde.Shutdown.logoutAndReboot

# Old interface:
dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest="org.kde.ksmserver" \
    /KSMServer org.kde.KSMServerInterface.logout int32:0 int32:1 int32:-1
```

or using the `qdbus` tool that comes with Qt:

```
# New interface:
qdbus org.kde.Shutdown /Shutdown logoutAndReboot

# Old interface:
qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 1 -1
```

See [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/ojpvwx/how_to_reboot_properly_from_the_cli/) for details on the parameters accepted by `logout` (together with a note that it's an old, KDE 3 era function).